# Does require and import on multiple files affect webpack module size?

Tags: webpack

If I have multiple files that require/import things I don't necessarily need in those files, will it increase the bundled output size or will webpack be smart enough to optimize it out?

Answer (score 0):

webpack does its best to do [tree shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/), but it's always better to not include stuff that you don't need.